# Clearcase finding a specific file on any branch

Tags: find, branch, clearcase

Our clearcase installation has multiple branches covering many years of development. I'm trying to search for a specific file (or part file name) and it could be on a branch that has never been merged back to the integration or MAIN branch.
Branch structure can be
main/branch1
and also
main/integration/branch2

Any thing i've seen on cleartool find needs a view but i've not be able to get a catch all config spec.

Any suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`cleartool find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) command does not depend always on a view config spec:

```
find [ pname... ] –a/ll [ –vis/ible | –nvi/sible ]
```

> You can also start with all objects in one or more VOBs, regardless of they are visible in a particular view

So you can use options `-all` and `-nvis` in order to search for *all* elements.

The view gives context for the command find to find the right vob (base on the `pname` argument.

The `-nvis` option will find elements, along with their branches and versions, that are *not* visible (do not have a standard path name) in the view.